# Why function length exclude rest parameters

Tags: javascript

Exploring [RambdaJS](https://ramdajs.com/) and found [curry](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) function that looks like this:

```
var addFourNumbers = (a, b, c, d) => a + b + c + d;

var curriedAddFourNumbers = R.curry(addFourNumbers);
var f = curriedAddFourNumbers(1, 2);
var g = f(3);
g(4); //=> 10
```

There are a lot of functional programming languages that provide currying out of the box, but in JS it looks like magic, how can you know what is function arity?

Answer is very easy, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

> The length property indicates the number of arguments expected by the
>   function.

```
function func1() {}
function func2(a, b) {}
console.log(func1.length);    // expected output: 0
console.log(func2.length);    // expected output: 2
```

But there is little catch about rest parameter, `length` excludes the rest parameter, and it looks very weird, for example let's consider:

```
function a(...d) { console.log(d) } // expected output: []
```

function `a` know for sure that it expect one parameter `d` and this parameter is array, so is there any reasonable sentence why JS exclude rest parameter or this behavior one of the [WAT JS](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) features?

Comment: You've misunderstood what `...` does. It specifically expects a variable number of parameters.

Comment: To get the expected output, you have to call `a()` (no arguments!), so surely you cannot say that `a` expects one argument?!

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear. OP wants to know why rest parameters are not included in the `.length` property, even though from *within the function itself*, they appear as a single argument (so it could be argued that `function foo(...args) {}` should have length 1).

Comment: [per mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) "The length property indicates the number of arguments expected by the function".  Given the rest parameter indicates a variable number of arguments, the `length` property is simply incompatible (conceptually) with rest parameters.  I think their choice of omitting rest parameters from the `length` count is as sensible a decision as any.

Comment: @aaaaaa I completely agree, and I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Sure - I was thinking it may not directly answer OP's question because it answers 'why is it omitted' with 'why would you do anything else' haha

Answer (score 2):

[per mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) (emphasis mine)

> The length property indicates the number of arguments **expected** by the function

Given the rest parameter indicates a variable number of arguments, the `length` property is conceptually incompatible with rest parameters. I think their choice of omitting rest parameters from the `length` count is as sensible a decision as any.

Comment: Here's the [ECMAScript spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-expectedargumentcount) for calculating the `Function.length` property. I'd note that not only are rest parameters omitted from the length, but also any parameters with default arguments.